# how to have bold and normal text in same textview in android?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have searched internet and tried the following code but its not working

```
SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString("Health: ");
           ss1.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, ss1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            textview1.setText("\n"+ss1+strhealth+"\n\n");
```

i want output to be like this 
**Health:** good

where strhealth = good
But it is coming out Health: good
What is the mistake ?

I am using android studio 2.1.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
textview1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Health:</b> good"));
```

The mistake in your code is to use string concatenation here: `"\n"+ss1+strhealth+"\n\n"` which strips out all formatting because the components are taken as normal strings.

Comment: if i don't concatenate then how can i put a variable and mutiple text in a single text view

Comment: I tried       textview1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Health:</b>")+strhealth+"\n\n");   but output is still not having Health: as bold

Comment: Same problem as in your original try. Use this: `textview1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Health:</b>"+strhealth+"\n\n"));`

Comment: thanks  its working but now i have to use html to format everything in text view.Now the properties of text view e.g. center is not working

Answer (score 26):

```
 String txt1="Health: ";
 SpannableString txtSpannable= new SpannableString(txt1);
 StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
 txtSpannable.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 8, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 builder.append(txtSpannable);

 String txt2="good";
 builder.append(txt2);

 textview1.lblStatus.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: It would be better to not hard-code the length of 8 but use txt1.length() instead.

Answer (score 10):

In kotlin, you can do this. I used this to bold characters/word within a string. For example:

> item = "Philippines"
>
> query = "Phil"
>
> result = **Phil**ippines

```
val spannable = SpannableString(item)
val indexStart = item.indexOf(query)
val indexEnd = indexStart + query.length
spannable.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), indexStart, indexEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

and use it like this

```
textView.text = spannable
```

Answer (score 7):

I am bit late to answer, but I created a method for easy use by using answer already provided here.

```
    private void setSpanString(String string1, String string2, TextView textView) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder=new SpannableStringBuilder();
    SpannableString txtSpannable= new SpannableString(string1);
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    txtSpannable.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, string1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    builder.append(txtSpannable);
    builder.append(string2);
   textView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a string resource such as this:

```
<string name="health_status"><b>Health:</b> %1$s</string>
```

When you want to set the health status just use this code:

```
String ss1 = getString(R.string.health_status, strhealth);
```

Answer (score 2):

---

Below I have mentioned the code which one through you can create spannableString in Kotlin

```
val spannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()

val boldSpan: StyleSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)

sp_text.setSpan(boldSpan, firstIndex, lastIndex,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

sp_text.setSpan(clickableSpan, firstIndex, lastIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            sp_text.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary)), firstIndex, lastIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use 2 different textView, a label and one for the data. it's common and good practice

Comment: Sometimes you have to process one string so it would require more work to split the strings to the appropriate textViews. So why not hit 2 birds with one stone when you can.