# How do I add bold to a custom font family then use it for strings?

Tags: android, fonts

I read on Stack Overflow how to create a custom bold font and a regular one:

[How to create custom font family with bold font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264614/how-to-create-custom-font-family-with-bold-font)

But I'm struggling to understand how to implement this in my strings. Ordinarily you simply use `<b></b>` to make text bold, but this doesn't seem to work with my custom fonts. All the text remains the same.

Comment: You need to provide the bold version of the font as well as the regular one. TTF fonts come in different files for regular, bold, italic bold-italic and so on. I guess otf fonts work the same way. In other words, each file contains a variant of the font-family.

Comment: But I have added both a regular and a bold font...

Comment: There may be something wrong the way you made the custom font.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have tried adding the bolded font to a font family, but it hasn't worked. You can try one of the ways below. It will work even if you do import a TTF font.

One way you can do it is in strings.xml
You can create a new string and then add the b to bold it like this:

```
<string name="my_string"><b> My String</b></string>
```

You will need to create one for each string that you want to bold. 
Then in your layout file, you can set the `android:text` to one of the strings from strings.xml and you can set the `android:fontFamily`to the TTF font.

You can also bold it programmatically using the SpannableString in Java. Check [this article to see how to bold programmatically.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661755/how-to-have-bold-and-normal-text-in-same-textview-in-android&ved=2ahUKEwjvruL5uMXeAhUi0oMKHf-0AdQQjjgwAHoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1KzENDSHAVeTT8AZmJ_79q) 
Hope it helps!